# How to set JMS Properties while sending message via pymqi to IBM MQ

Tags: python, jms, ibm-mq, pymqi

I want to set some jms properties while sending a message using pymqi to support different message parameters.

## Below code is for reference only

```
import pymqi

queue_manager = 'QM1'

channel = 'DEV.APP.SVRCONN'

host = '127.0.0.1' 

port = '1414' 

queue_name = 'TEST.1' 

message = 'Hello from Python!' 

conn_info = '%s(%s)' % (host, port) 

qmgr = pymqi.connect(queue_manager, channel, conn_info)

queue = pymqi.Queue(qmgr, queue_name)

queue.put(message)

queue.close()

qmgr.disconnect()
```

Comment: Have you reviewed the pymqi github issues list:  I think there is an issue there related to message properties.  In base MQ (not JMS or XMS) you would set message properties which would be available to a JMS app as JMS properties.

Comment: See this example: https://github.com/dsuch/pymqi/blob/master/code/examples/message_property_set.py